# How to synchronise threads and preserve their execution order with CyclingBarrier?

Tags: java, multithreading, runnable, synchronized, java.util.concurrent

I want to write a multithread app that prints characters from Strings one by one and after first "round" it would preserve order for the other rounds. It should work somehting like this:

For Strings:

`private String[] strings = {"aaaa", "bb", "ccccccccccccc", "dddddd"};`

It would print:

`abcd abcd acd acd cd cd c c c c c c c`

or maybe

`dbac dbac dac dac dc dc c c c c c c c`

depending on which proccess started first in the very first round

My solution so far looks like this

```
import java.util.concurrent.BrokenBarrierException;
import java.util.concurrent.CyclicBarrier;

public class Printer {

    private CyclicBarrier cyclicBarrier;

    private final static String one = "aaa";
    private final static String two = "bbbb";
    private final static String three = "c";
    private final static String four = "dddddd";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Printer printer = new Printer();
        printer.runSimulation(4);
    }

    private void runSimulation(int numberOfStrings) {
        cyclicBarrier = new CyclicBarrier(numberOfStrings, new AggregatorThread());

        Thread thread = new Thread(new PrintingThread(padSpaces(one, 10)));
        Thread thread1 = new Thread(new PrintingThread(padSpaces(two, 10)));
        Thread thread3 = new Thread(new PrintingThread(padSpaces(three, 10)));
        Thread thread4 = new Thread(new PrintingThread(padSpaces(four, 10)));
        thread.start();
        thread1.start();
        thread3.start();
        thread4.start();
    }

    class AggregatorThread implements Runnable{
        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.print("  ");
        }
    }

    class PrintingThread implements Runnable{

        private String toPrint;
        private int iterator;

        public PrintingThread(String toPrint) {
            this.toPrint = toPrint;
            this.iterator = 0;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            while(iterator < toPrint.length()) {
                System.out.print(toPrint.charAt(iterator));
                iterator++;
                try {
                    cyclicBarrier.await();
                } catch (InterruptedException | BrokenBarrierException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private String padSpaces(String inputString, int length) {
        if (inputString.length() >= length) {
            return inputString;
        }
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        while (sb.length() < length - inputString.length()) {
            sb.append(' ');
        }
        StringBuilder sb1 = new StringBuilder(inputString);
        sb1.append(sb);

        return sb1.toString();
    }
}
```

But it doesn't preserve the order of letters written to the console and also i fill the Strings to the some hardcoded value right now, but i would want to make it work properly without equal strings.
Any suggestions on this?

Comment: Threads don't work that way. That's the whole reason for having barriers. You'll have to execute them sequentially if you want them executed sequentially.

Comment: There are definitely ways to do this, but since you're asking 'with `CyclicBarrier`', I think you might be misunderstanding the purpose of a `CyclicBarrier` :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're asking for a solution with `CyclicBarrier`, here's *a* way you could do this with one...  It definitely wouldn't be my first thought for how to solve the issue though (assuming the issue isn't 'do this with a `CyclicBarrier`'...).

- Create a `CyclicBarrier` of length 4.
- Assign each `Thread` a *number* (0 to 3) when it starts (using an `AtomicInteger` or otherwise).
- Have each `Thread` do something like:

  ```
  while (barrier.getNumberWaiting() != this.threadNumber) {
  }

  // Do your adding to the StringBuilder here...

  barrier.await();
  ```

I.e. each `Thread` spins until the number of waiting parties is equal to that `Thread`'s number.

Whichever is assigned 0 will always go through first, while all the others are stuck spinning.  Once that `Thread` has done its `StringBuilder` thing, it will then `await`, which in turn frees the `Thread` assigned 1 to go through.  The order will stay consistent after the number assignments.

---

To get the unique id per process, a simple `AtomicInteger` can be used.

```
private final AtomicInteger idCounter = new AtomicInteger();
private final CyclicBarrier barrier = new CyclicBarrier(4);
private final AtomicInteger doneCounter = new AtomicInteger();

public Runnable createRunnable() {
    return () -> {
        final int threadId = this.idCounter.getAndIncrement();

        boolean threadDone = false;
        boolean moreCharacters = true;
        while (true) {
            while (this.barrier.getNumberWaiting() != threadId) {
            }

            // Add to StringBuilder here...

            // Set the 'moreCharacters' flag as false once this thread
            // has handled its String.
            // They will still need to spin though, to make sure the
            // parties waiting keep adding up as appropriate.

            if (!moreCharacters && !threadDone) {

                // 'threadDone' used so that each thread only
                // increments the 'doneCounter' once.

                this.doneCounter.incrementAndGet();
                threadDone = true;
            }

            barrier.await();

            if (this.doneCounter.get() == 4) {
                // Exit out of the loop once all Threads are done.
                break;
            }
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Right now according to your algorithm my program prints the right output with say: abcd acbd abc ab a, but since i pass the `threadNumber` in the constructor the results always get print in the same order, so how can i generate the unique id of a proccess when it invokes it's `run()` method?

Comment: @AdamGłowacki: Added a more thorough example which (hopefully) covers your question.  As I said above though, I'd be surprised if this was any better than doing them sequentially.  Without using a `CyclicBarrier`, there are much better ways to parellilise this kind of thing.  I haven't handled `Exception`s here, so this won't compile as is.  But it's a sketch.